# How colors are determined by heatmap in R?

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I am using R to make a heatmap from values in a matrix.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
a <- structure(c(16, 10, 7, 8, 12, 1, 9, 11, 20, 15, 5, 8, 9, 14, 11, 5, 6, 2, 9, 6, 9, 6, 12, 11, 11), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
heatmap(a, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Oranges"))(5))
```

The matrix looks like the following.

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   16    1    5    5    9
[2,]   10    9    8    6    6
[3,]    7   11    9    2   12
[4,]    8   20   14    9   11
[5,]   12   15   11    6   11
```

The heatmap looks like this.

[image]

Something is weird. `a[2, 1]` is 10 and is shown as dark red (blue circle). `a[3, 2]` is 11 and is shown as orange (green circle). Why does a bigger value have a lighter color than a smaller value?
How does `heatmap` or `image` decide the color for each grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/heatmap):

> scale: character indicating if the values should be centered and
> scaled in either the row direction or the column direction,
> or none.  The default is ‘"row"’ if ‘symm’ false, and
> ‘"none"’ otherwise.

By default it is set to `scale="row"`. To get exact, you need to do `scale="none"`:

```
colnames(a) = paste0("col",1:5)
rownames(a) = paste0("row",1:5)

    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
row1   16    1    5    5    9
row2   10    9    8    6    6
row3    7   11    9    2   12
row4    8   20   14    9   11
row5   12   15   11    6   11

heatmap(a, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, 
col=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Oranges"))(5),
scale="none")
```

[image]

You can think of the colors being spaced equally from 0 to 1. In your example with 5 colors, 0-0.2 will be the first color, 0.21-0.4 will be the second and so on. What remains is to normalize your values onto a 0-1 scale and placing them into the respective color.

In the above code, we did not scale by row or column, so we can use some part of the relevant code from [image.R](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/graphics/R/image.R) and we try to show it manually using a dotplot:

```
Col = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Oranges"))(5)

idx = which(!is.na(a),arr.ind=TRUE)
z = c(a)    
zlim = range(z)
nc = length(Col)
z = (z - zlim[1L])/diff(zlim)
zi = floor((nc - 1e-5) * z + 1e-7)

plot(idx[,2],idx[,1],col=Col[zi+1],pch=15,cex=4,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
axis(1,at=1:nc,colnames(a))
axis(2,at=1:nc,rownames(a))
```

[image]